# Is it possible to remove the USB ports and others I/O ports from a standard Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, gpio, camera, case

We're using Raspberry Pi 3's as prototypes but don't need the USB ports, as well as some of the other ports. Are they easily removable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove some or all of the USB ports, and/or the Ethernet jack if required. Adafruit has a [guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/diet-raspberry-pi) on reducing the USB and Ethernet ports. Node's taken it [even farther](https://n-o-d-e.net/pislim.html). There's more to it than can reasonably be summarized here, unfortunately.

You might also look at other boards. There are slimmer quad core boards available from [NanoPi](http://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=69), [Orange Pi](http://www.orangepi.org/OrangePiZeroPlus2/) and others if you just need a basic board.